# Nginx: running wordpress in subfolder of a Symfony2 app

Tags: php, wordpress, symfony, nginx

I run a Symfony2 app with nginx and want to integrate a wordpress installation in a subfolder of the public web-folder.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com          -> Symfony 2
http://www.example.com/magazin  -> Wordpress
```

With the origin nginx configuration of the Symfony app i can sucessfully make requests to the start-page of wordpress and also the whole admin-area including plugin installation and so on.

But since i configured wordpress to use a custom url scheme "year/month/title" for the posts, the request ends up in a 404. I figured out, that not wordpress is the application who gets the request, but symfony, which certainly doesnt know what to do here. The URL that wordpress creates for a post, is correct (e.g. http://www.example.com/magazin/2015/12/my-interesing-post).

Is it possible, to extend the nginx configuration in a way to handle all requests below the specific folder "/magazin/" and if so, how?

This is my nginx configuration, which currently handles only the Symfony2 application:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name           www.example.de;


  index  app.php index.php index.html;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/www.example.de.access.log combined;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/www.example.de.error.log;

  location ~ \.php$ {

    root          /data/www/www.example.de/current/web;
    include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    try_files     $uri $uri/ /app.php?$query_string;

    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index app_prod.php;
    fastcgi_param X_FORWARD_PORT "80";
    fastcgi_param CUSTOMER_ENV customer_default;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location / {

    root      /data/www/www.example.de/current/web;
    index     app.php index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$query_string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending to malcolms explanation, this should do the work:

(If your log says that the path of the default nginx dir is prepended, you just have to define the root directory again)

```
location /magazin {
    root      /data/www/www.example.de/current/web;
    index     index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /magazin/index.php?q=$uri;
}
```

Additionally, I'm not pretty sure but I would suggest to insert this location block before any other location block that could fetch this route (location /magazin and afterwards location /).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using symfony2 with php7, you can try this configuration:

```
server {
  listen    *:80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com/web/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;
  access_log off;

  location @rewriteapp {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
  }

  location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
       expires max;
       try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location / {
      index app.php;
      try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
  }

  # BLOG AREA START
  location @rewriteblog {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }

  location @rewriteblogadmin {
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /blog/wp-admin/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
  }

  location = /blog/favicon.ico {
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
  }

  location = /blog/robots.txt {
      allow all;
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
  }

  location /blog {
      # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
      # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
      try_files $uri @rewriteblog;
  }

  location /blog/wp-admin {
      # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
      # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
      try_files $uri @rewriteblogadmin;
  }

  # BLOG
  location ~ ^/(blog|blog\/wp-admin)/(.*)\.php(/|$) {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      include fastcgi_params;

      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
      fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
      fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
  }

  # PROD
  # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
  # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
  location ~ ^/(app|config)\.php(/|$) {
      fastcgi_index app.php;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
  }

  # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
  # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
  location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
  }

  error_log /var/log/nginx/examplecom_error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/examplecom_access.log;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `location` with your subfolder:

```
location /magazin {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /magazin/index.php?q=$uri;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, this will route all requests /magazin/* to index.php, also all .css/.js/.jpg-Requests, which end up now with 404

Comment: Try to change the last line to: `try_files $uri $uri/ /magazin/index.php;`

Comment: doesn't help. static files won't be accessed even if the path could be ensured being valid on the filesystem directly on the server

Comment: I'm not on nginx now, so cannot check, but another thing: add slash after magazin: `location /magazin/ {`