# Running Wordpress on a subfolder within a Laravel app on NGINX

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx

I'm having trouble configuring wordpress on a subfolder of my Laravel app on Laravel Forge (server is powered by nginx).

The Wordpress-app is located under `/home/forge/my-domain.com/public/blog` (`my-domain.com` contains my laravel app).

I've tried several answers from other questions here on SO, but I keep getting errors (mostly "too many redirects" or "502 bad gateway").

This is my current solution (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568960/nginx-running-wordpress-in-subfolder-of-a-symfony2-app) - resulting in a 502 bad gateway, also for the admin-area of my wordpress-app):

```
# BLOG START
location @rewriteblog {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location @rewriteblogadmin {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /blog/wp-admin/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location = /blog/favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /blog/robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location /blog {
    try_files $uri @rewriteblog;
}

location /blog/wp-admin {
    try_files $uri @rewriteblogadmin;
}

location ~ ^/(blog|blog\/wp-admin)/(.*)\.php(/|$) {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
#BLOG-END
```

Another attempt was this (502 Bad Gateway):

```
location /blog {
    root      /home/forge/my-domain.com/public/blog;
    index     index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri;
}
```

Another attempt was this (Admin-Area and startpage accessible, posts result in too many redirects):

```
location /blog {
    root      /home/forge/my-domain.com/public/;
    index     index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?q=$uri;
}
```

Another attempt was this (Admin-Area and startpage too many redirect, posts accessible):

```
location /blog {
    root      /home/forge/faaren.com/public/blog;
    index     index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri;
}
```

Any ideas how to configure my nginx to get this done?

Answer (score 3):

Keep things simple, starting from a working state, then extend.

You didn't post your Laravel part of NGINX config, but let us assume that the essentials of it are:

```
root /home/forge/my-domain.com/public;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass ...
}
```

Now let's say we add a `/blog/` with different `root` as you specified:

```
location /blog/ {
    root /home/forge/my-domain.com/public/blog; 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Why this doesn't work is because for `/blog/` URL, NGINX literally checks the existence (`try_files`) of `/home/forge/my-domain.com/public/blog` (specified `root`) + `/blog/index.php` (request URI).

If you set the `root` to the parent folder (as in, same to Laravel's webroot; in other words, not specify it at all), then NGINX tries: `/home/forge/my-domain.com/public` (root) + `/blog/index.php` (request URI), which is correct.

For a `/blog/foo` kind of URL (SEO friendly), you want NGINX to use `root` + `/blog/index.php`.

Thus, the complete config:

```
root /home/forge/my-domain.com/public;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
location /blog/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment but I was stumbling around an issue with wp rest api after attempting to do the above. The issue only occured when I changed my permalink from the default plain to a custom or when I activated some specific plugins, so troubleshooting was not easy. @Danila Vershinin solution worked like magic and I cannot thank him enough. This has saved me so much frustration

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32342449)