How to setup WordPress on a Laravel subdirectory?
I'm working on a Laravel project and must set up a WordPress project at the /blog route. I already added a server block on the Nginx Configuration and updated the .htaccess file rules but the WordPress project isn't working. Please let me know if I anything missed here. Thank you.
My Nginx configuration is:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root /root/example/public;
    index index.php;

    # Ensure proper handling of Laravel requests
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ^~ /blog/ {
        root /root/example/public/blog;
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # PHP-FPM configuration
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files (if any exist)
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    # Logs
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/laravel_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/laravel_access.log;
}

and My .htacc file is on the public folder is:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /blog/
    
    # Ensure WordPress works from the /blog directory
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    
    # Rewrite all other requests to WordPress index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


Explain what "isn't working" means.

Also, .htaccess is strictly an Apache concept. NGINX doesn't process it at all, so it's completely irrelevant in this case.

How does Laravel factor in your question? It looks like you are just having problems setting up Wordpress.

Are you using nginx, or Apache?  If nginx, your .htaccess is ignored, and you need to configure both WP and Laravel for nginx.  Have you tried any of the other examples here doing what you are trying to do?  Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524294/running-wordpress-on-a-subfolder-within-a-laravel-app-on-nginx?
